# Она села рядом с мужем, чтобы он не заснул во время обеда и не пролил бы суп на себя

Tags: наклонение, сослагательное

*Она села рядом с мужем, **чтобы он не заснул во время обеда и не пролил бы суп на себя.***

Выделенный фрагмент - СПП цели, так? (частица *бы* "слившаяся" с *что* + форма на -*л*). 
Как можно объяснить повторное употребление частицы *бы* при глаголе *пролил*? это какой-то особый стилистическй прием? эмфаза?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что выделенный фрагмент действительно является придаточным цели, потому что можно задать вопрос от главного к придаточному предложению: она села (с какой целью?), чтобы он не заснул. А вот частица *бы*, употребленная с глаголом *пролил*, меня ставит в тупик. Скажите, а где вы увидели это предложение? Я считаю, что *бы* здесь вообще не нужна, это ошибка. Оба глагола должны стоять в одном и том же наклонении, иначе получается какая-то неразбериха: в данном случае вообще непонятно, зачем нужно было употреблять частицу.

Comment: пример из одной книги, которую мне надо анализировать
я сказала бы, что глаголы стоят в одном наклонении - сослагательном - (при глаголе "заснул" частица "бы" как бы вошла в состав союза "что", а при глаголе "пролил" переводчик повторяет ее)... Вопрос - для чего? не знаю : (

Answer (score 1):

Да, это ССП цели. 
Не знаю, как грамматически квалифицировать эту "повторную" частицу, но она вполне законна и нужна.
В данном случае можно и опустить, не критично, хотя ощущение какой-то шершавости все равно появляется при опущенной частице, не хватает чего-то.

Но стоит чуть изменить фразу - и без повторения "бы" в устной речи сразу возникает двусмысленность:

*Она села рядом с матерью, чтобы она не заснула во время обеда(,) и не пролила суп на себя.*

Без "бы" на слух непонятно, кто суп не пролил. Так что это не эмфаза, частица нужна и по грамматике.

Ну а если возвращаться к грамматике исторической, то ничего странного тут нет. Современная частица "бы" - это рефлекс давно забытой временн**о**й формы глагола "быть" (*одного из видов аориста, 2-3 лицо: "быхъ"*). И грамматика требовала повторения этого "бы/быхъ" при каждом глаголе: *"Пошел бы ты в огород, нарвал бы петрушки, покрошил бы, да бросил бы в суп"* - хоть десять раз повторить, не криминал, хотя на современный слух достаточно только первого и последнего.

Так и в нашем случае, первое "бы" слилось с "что", последнее сохранилось в неизменном виде. Все законно, фраза корректна.

(+)
И конечно же, ни о каком изъявительном наклонении, что с "бы", что без неё, речи идти не может. Это вопрос грамматики сослагательного наклонения.

(++)
Ой, ещё момент. У нас же *отрицание.* А отрицание в аналитических формах отрицает вспомогательный глагол, не смысловой.

*"Я не буду писать" vs "я не писать буду"* - почувствуйте разницу. Так вот с частицей "бы" то же самое, в историческом аспекте случай просто тождественный. "Не" относится к не столько к смысловому глаголу, сколько к вспомогательной частице (тоже когда-то бывшей вспомогательным глаголом). Так что, если удалять сослагательную частицу "бы", то только вместе с отрицательной "не". Вот почему и "не хватало" чего-то во фразе с опущенной частицей.

Но без "не" тут вообще ерунда получается, грамматика не выдерживает, смысл ускользает.

Comment: "Она села рядом с матерью, чтобы она не заснула во время обеда(,) и не пролила суп на себя". Всё определяется запятой. Без запятой: она села поближе, чтобы ***мать*** не заснула и не пролила (однородные члены). С запятой звучит странно, но если написать так, смысл будет следующий: она села рядом, чтобы мать не заснула, и при этом независимо от этого почему-то **она сама** не пролила на себя суп (логики не видно, однако).

Comment: Да? ))) Я не знаю, что у вас там странно звучит, но у меня это начинается, когда мне говорят про запятую **в устной речи**.

Comment: А-а, Вы о том, что когда эту фразу произнесут, а не напишут, возникает двусмысленность! С этим согласен, конечно, просто не понял, о чём речь, простите.

Comment: Да ладно))) Это не я говорю в общем-то. Тут штука такая, что грамматику надо постигать через уши и язык. А сомнительную - в первую очередь. Когда говорите или читаете вслух сразу чувствуете, что здесь что-то не так. Глаза тут хуже работают. Поэтому метод верный, попробуйте при случае, если не знали. Я просто считал это само собой разумеющимся для всх меня читающих, не оговорил.

Answer (score 0):

В примере, который Вы приводите, сослагательное наклонение указывает на гипотетическое действие, которое может произойти, если муж заснет. Использование изъявительного наклонения вместо сослагательного указывало бы на уверенность говорящего в том,что действие обязательно произойдет, если муж уснет.

Comment: Серж, но здесь ведь нет изъяв.наклонения...

Comment: Я не говорил, что здесь изъявительное наклонение. Внимательно прочитайте мой ответ.

Comment: да, простите, Вы правы, я Вас не так поняла... но что касается сосл. накл. мне это было понятно, мой вопрос касался повторной частицы "бы"...

Comment: В русской корпусной грамматике говорится: Частица бы (б) может быть использована при одном предикате дважды или более в разных местах клаузы. C точки зрения норм литературного языка такие конструкции считаются ошибочными (см., например, [Розенталь 1985:293]). Примеры удвоенной частицы чаще обнаруживаются в устных текстах, чем в письменных. Удвоение частицы типично для контекстов с ***союзами если (бы) и чтобы***: Сколько я ни наблюдал за ними, никогда я не видел, чтобы муравьи просто сидели бы на месте и ничего не делали. [В. Медведев. Баранкин, будь человеком! (1957)]

Comment: Помнится, покойный В.С.Черномырдин любил повторно употреблять частицу "бы": "Я хочу, чтобы Вы ответили бы мне..." А вот у В.М.шукшина роман называется: "Я пришел, чтобы дать вам волю", а не " ...чтобы дать бы  вам волю"